# Is there a way to share Mozilla certificates with Chrome?

Tags: certificates

Is there anyway I can share Mozilla certificates with Chrome to make Chrome working properly as when I want to go for ex wikipedia as now the message says it is not private connection. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.I tried to export it form Mozilla and import to Chrome with no big success.
Thanks in advance for any tips